# Why isn't my method finding Word docs working?

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm trying to find all the Word files in the `Documents` folder and for some reason my method isn't working. I've confirmed that it successfully goes through all the directories, but for some reason it isn't finding the Word docs when look at the extension a la

```
    private void _WalkDirectoryTree ( DirectoryInfo root )
    {
        try
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo[] files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
            if ( files != null )
            {
                foreach ( System.IO.FileInfo fi in files.Where(f => f.Extension.StartsWith("doc")) )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Found Word file: " + fi.FullName + "\n");
                        //string text = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName);
                    }
                    catch ( Exception E )
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Ignored exception when reading text from file: " + E.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

            DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = root.GetDirectories();
            if ( subDirs != null )
            {
                foreach ( DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs )
                {
                    this._WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( UnauthorizedAccessException UAE )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception encountered and ignored: " + UAE.Message);
        }
    }

    private void _CrawlDocuments ( )
    {
        DirectoryInfo DocumentsFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),"Documents"));
        this._WalkDirectoryTree(DocumentsFolder);
    }
```

So what is the correct `Where` clause that I should be using? I've tried MIME type and referring to http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-summary-list/ but it's like Word docs are invisible.

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? You'd see that the extension is `".doc"` instead of `"doc"`. Also, why not let `GetFiles` take care of this: `root.GetFiles("*.doc")`?

Comment: Side note, you should use `EnumerateFiles` and `EnumerateDirectories` especially if the directories are large